# perl sorting - how to output the row number matched data fields

Tags: regex, perl, sorting, match, substring

I have a file that looks like this:

```
ID
1
3
3
6
7
1
1
16
X
```

I want to loop through for each line and if it matches 1, extract the row number.  In my code it works for two digit numbers (11, 12, 13...) but for single digit it does not work.  It produces an empty output file.   i tried with the substring substr($data[$j],0 ); to catch the whole string in the field but it doesn't work at all then. How can I fix this?

```
print "\nRead list file in\n";
open(FILE, "list.txt") or die("Unable to open file");
my @data = <FILE>; # this is the whole filestored
my $data_size = @data;

 ##name the input
print "Which number do you want to sort out?";
my $input = <>;
chomp($input);
print "\n";


 ## for each line of the file get the column numbers to cut based on input number
open OUTPUT, ">$input.txt";  
print OUTPUT "0 \n";

for (my $j =0; $j < $data_size; $j++){

    my $match = substr($data[$j],0,2);
    if ($match eq $input){
        print OUTPUT "$j\n";
    }       
}
print "data is in the files ";
```

Comment: You probably need to `chomp @data` after reading it in.

Comment: @MarkSetchell looks like that works!  Can you explain why?

Comment: When you read in the file, you get a linefeed at the end of each element in the array, so if you have a single digit in the line, the two characters you extract with your `substr` are a digit and a linefeed which will not match a digit. I'll make it as an answer for all to see if you would care to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to `chomp()` the array `@data` after you read it in to remove linefeeds, like this:

```
print "\nRead list file in\n";
open(FILE, "list.txt") or die("Unable to open file");
my @data = <FILE>; # this is the whole filestored

chomp @data;
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that the date you have read into `@data` has newlines at the end of each line, while you are using `chomp` on the string input from the terminal so that can never match.

If you are matching a two-digit number then `substr $data[$j], 0, 2` will remove the newline for you, but anything short remains untouched.

You could just `chomp @data`, but there are another few details that could be improved, so this is a rewrite that should be useful

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "\nRead list file in\n";
open my $in_fh, '<', 'list.txt' or die "Unable to open 'list.txt' for input: $!";
chomp(my @data = <$in_fh>);
close $in_fh;

print "Which number do you want to sort out_fh?";
chomp(my $input = <>);
print "\n";

open my $out_fh, '>', "$input.txt" or die "Unable to open '$input.txt' for output: $!";
print $out_fh "0 \n";

my $found;

for my $j (0 .. $#data) {
  my ($match) = $data[$j] =~ /(\d+)/;
  next unless $match;
  if ($match == $input) {
    print $out_fh "$j\n";
    $found = 1;
  }
}
print "Data is in the files\n" if $found;
```